# Using Objective-C JSONModel with an array of objects as entry point

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa, jsonmodel

I got a json objects which starts with an array of objects. I wanna use [JSONModel](https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel) together with this json object but I can't find an example how to do this.

Here's my json:

```
{
  "days": [{
    "date": "2016-12-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    "items": [{ ... }]
  },{
    "date": ...
  }
}
```

I created a DaysModel

```
@interface DaysModel : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic) NSArray<DayModel *> *days;
```

And the corresponding DayModel (in fact, I only need an Array of "DayModel Types")

```
@interface DaysModel : JSONModel

@property (nonatomic) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray<ItemModel *> *items;
```

But when initializing my Model with a string

```
DaysModel *myDays = [[DaysModel alloc] initWithString:teststring error:&jsonError];
```

The content of myDays.days will be an Array of Dictionaries instead of an Array of DayModels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you forgot to add the protocol, try to read the documentation on github?

https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel#model-collections

try to add

```
@protocol ItemModel;
```

in `DaysModel`

and change from:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray<ItemModel *> *items;
```

to:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray<ItemModel> *items;
```

Comment: This gave me a idea to fix my issue :) Thanks @kikko088